# What is "SFC Tool > Warning: Overlap: Duplicate ownership for directory"? Windows Server 2019 (cbs.log)

Tags: windows, logging, windows-server-2019, dism, sfc

After a couple days on cleanup of one of my windows server 2019 servers, using a combination of SFC, DISM, Component manager DCOM manual permissions changes, Registry Editor changes etc,

the bulk of the remaining warnings in the cbs.log are of the type "Warning: Overlap: Duplicate ownership for directory", approximately 800 log entries (235KB of the 3.6MB log)

Not a lot of info to be found on this type of entry, many tech bloggers recommend to ignore this type of duplicate ownership issue as they (in general) should not impact OS health.

But I would like to know is:

1. How these types of dup issues were generated in the first place
2. What impact the dup ownership issue might have on current and future upgrades, installs and use of the server.
3. How to resolve? for example - would i need to manually evaluate and fix each log entry via Registry changes?

I suspect that a renamed computer might have caused many of these dup ownership entries, due to users and specifically administrator accounts and SID's changing due to that computer name change, leaving orphan unknown SID/accounts.

Note that all the 800 entries report they are of a **nonSxS** type, example below.  I assume that just infers these files are not stored within %windir%\WinSxS\ (component store)

2021-02-17 16:27:47, Info                  CSI    00006c70 Warning: Overlap: Duplicate ownership for directory ??\C:\Windows\SysWOW64\fi-FI in component Microsoft-Windows-Cdosys.Resources, version 10.0.17763.1, arch x86, culture [l:5]'fi-FI', nonSxS, pkt {l:8 b:31bf3856ad364e35}

Any additional nuggets of related info/advice are most welcome!